# FTP upload to my site (NOT Brick FTP) from Zapier?

Tags: ftp, zapier

I'm trying to set up a zap that will pull an e-mail attachment from OWA (Outlook Web Access) and upload it to my organization's web site.  The only pre-configured FTP option is BrickFTP, and I'd like to avoid getting another service involved if possible.  Is there a way to perform an FTP upload from Zapier to an FTP server other than BrickFTP?

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I would love to see this feature in Zapier!! In the meantime, integromat does have an FTP integration that works well.

About [integromat](https://www.integromat.com/?pc=sdm18) [aff]:

- the learning curve is much steeper than zapier, and the interface is complex! This complexity offers cool features like arrays: If you take the time to learn it you can have a really powerful setup.
- The free plan is highly functional, but make sure you don't accidentally eat up your 1000 action allowance with, for example, an email integration that goes off for every message.
- You can make integromat work nicely with Zapier. I have a sequence where Podio triggers a Zap that adds Folders to dropbox, then my integromat scenario sends the new folder structure to my FTP server.

This is an old post but several of us have viewed it so I thought I'd offer the solution that's working for me. Hope it helps some of you!